# Data structure to use for platformer game map

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I'm writing a 2D platformer game using Java for Android.

Currently I have all game entities (except for the avatar, stored in an array of array of "Entity"

```
Entity[][]
```

Whenever I need to check something - such as what I'm going to draw on screen or for collision detection - I simply grab a small radius of items around the avatar and do whatever using a system of inheritance and polymorphism.

The problem is that this means I can only put one entity in a particular grid coordinate. This used to be quite okay for the most part - but now I have moving items (such as enemies or moving blocks) - which when they collide, end up deleting one another basically they get overwritten.

So what data structure should I use? I was thinking of something like

```
ArrayList<Entity>[][]
```

But that's going to be very expensive, and a waste of memory since duplicate items are the exception not the rule.

I was also considering separating the moving items into their own `ArrayList`, and looping through all of them, but that's an ugly solution.

So any ideas on what I could use? I want something which is pretty fast, but not too memory intensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two-dimensional array for storing entities wastes memory (most blocks won't be occupied) and doesn't allow overlapping entities, as you noticed.  With few entities, a simple ArrayList (no visible arrays involved) is probably going to be fully adequate.

If you have lots of entities, you could consider a quad-tree data structure or some other spatial indexing structure (check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index).

As a simpler and more "traditional" approach, how about keeping a two-layer view of your entities-- an ArrayList of all active (visible) ones, and an ArrayList of all inactive (too-far-away-to-care) ones?  If performance matters, you can disable collision detection on the latter and perform little or no AI/maintenance on them.

Comment: I used a quadtree once (was making an N body gravity simulator) - but I have no idea how I'd use a quadtree in this context. The game doesn't have small 'screens', but rather a large continuous one - or would it just load more than one quadrant automatically and then allow me to do the spatial query for a smaller set? Am I understanding it wrongly?

Comment: For each entity you'd search for a rectangle around that entity to check for collisions:  http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374  As an optimisation, you can first check whether the bounds are fully contained within the entity's quadrant in the quad tree (in which case you just use that quadrant as possible entities to collide against).

Comment: To elaborate:  unlike what the article says, you can use the quad tree as your exclusive storage, and remove and re-add entities when they pass quadrant boundaries.  Or you can base yourself off a global ArrayList<Entity> and work as the article suggested.  But the sole point of the quad tree is to speed up collision detection, which is also probably the only reason for why you were using the Entity[][] in the beginning.

Comment: I'm using it for collision detection and for drawing the view. Interesting article, I'll take a read. Thanks.

Comment: Right-- that's the other use case.  But there again the quad tree's ability to give you all the objects in a particular rectangle (plus a few on the side) comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

What about you keep the entities as:

```
Entity[][]
```

And assuming you look-up entities, like:

```
Entity e = entities[i][j]
```

But keeping you enemies in a:

```
Map<String,List<Entity>> map
```

Where the key is the String made by concatenating i and j with a random middle character (e.g. "1.15" if i==1 and j==15). Now you keep the fast look-up of entities and also have fast look-up (albeit not as fast as an array) of enemies without the excess empty space.

Comment: The problem is that I think this is also very expensive. To move a single entity from another one, I'd need to create a new list, put the entity in it, look for the old list and potentially delete it, then put it into the hashmap. I do agree its far better than An array of List<Entity>, but there is still a lot of overhead in my opinion.